# How can I set the tick marks of the x axis in RectangleChart?

Tags: graphics

By default, the x-axis in `RectangleChart` is not labeled. Using `Axis -> {True, True}` does not help. Can I set the ticks manually?

Comment: @R.M ticks was what was I after (I fixed the title).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default `RectangleChart` leaves spaces between the bars and uses categorical axes, similar to `BarChart`.  If you set `BarSpacing -> None`, no space is left and you get a regular axis with a quantitative scale on it:

[image]

Comment: This example seems not to work under Mathematica 9.

Comment: @KarstenW. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

```
 RectangleChart[vekk = {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {3, 4}}, 
 ChartLabels -> Placed[Flatten@vekk[[All, 2]], Axis], 
 BarSpacing -> None, FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {None, None}}, 
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {False, False}}, Ticks -> None]
```

[image: Label & Ticks]